# Method chaining for derived DataFrame class

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to extend a pandas DataFrame by the following code

```
class CustomFrame(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        DataFrame.__init__(self,{"a":[1,2,3,4],"b":[5,6,7,8]})
    def get(self):
        return self.loc[1]
    def foo(self):
        return 2*self
```

Now I wanted to chain method calls like:

```
>>> c=CustomFrame()
>>> c.get().foo()
'Series' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

obviously `.loc` returns a Series which doesn't know anything about the custom `foo` method. Is there any way to make this work?

**Edit:**

Ideally I would like to do something like

```
c.method_from_data_frame().method_from_custom_frame().another_method_from_data_frame()
```

Following the advice of HYRY I've overridden the constructor of `DataFrame`, however I need to set some properties on initialisation of CustomFrame

```
class CustomFrame(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(CustomFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.c = kw.get('c',False)

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return CustomFrame

   >>> c=CustomFrame(c=5)
   >>> print c.c
   5
   >>> print c.get().c
   False
```

I tried to use `functools` `partial`

```
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return partial(CustomFrame,c=5)
```

but I get a `pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!` error. Another way would be to change `get` to

```
    def get(self):
        ret =  self.loc[[1]] # CustomFrame with default .c
        ret.c = self.c
        return ret
```

which seems not very elegant

Comment: Either override `loc` to return a `CustomFrame`, or convert its return value in `get`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe mmmh overriding `DataFrame.loc` implies overriding every method which return value I possibly want to chain.

Comment: Well... yes, otherwise you won't get a `CustomFrame`. I suppose you could do something with `__getattribute__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `_constructor` property, here is an example, because `self.loc[1]` returns a series object, I changed it to `self.loc[[1]]`:

```
from pandas import DataFrame


class CustomFrame(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(CustomFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return CustomFrame        

    def get(self):
        return self.loc[[1]]

    def foo(self):
        return 2*self

c=CustomFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4],"b":[5,6,7,8]})
print c.get().foo()
```

**Edit**

I have not better idea to copy attributes, maybe you can use `_metadata` or Decorator, here is an example with decorator:

```
def copy_attrs(func):
    def wrap_func(self, *args, **kw):
        res = func(self, *args, **kw)
        res.c = self.c
        return res
    return wrap_func

class CustomFrame(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.__dict__["c"] = kw.pop("c", None)    
        super(CustomFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return CustomFrame

    @copy_attrs
    def get(self):
       return self.loc[:2]

df = CustomFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4],"b":[5,6,7,8]}, c=100)
print df.c, df.get().c
```

Comment: Interesting, can this somehow be extended so that I can pass/initialize properties on the created `CustomFrame`?

Comment: @greole, can you add an example?